# Flutter TextField with hyperlinks

Tags: flutter

I want to create a Text Field in which user should be able to to enter hyperlink into the text box and that hyperlink color is come up blue and hyperlink is clickable.

Is there any package available for it or any way to achieve it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

these packages can help you to do it.

[link_text](https://pub.dev/packages/link_text)

[flutter_linkify](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify)

Comment: I think these are text widgets not Text Field widget

Comment: You can use text as Text Field.
add some transparent Text Field over your text and add data of Text Field in text.
There is not any Text Field with hiperlink detector.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - you can use the LinkText package available at: https://pub.dev/packages/link_text

**First update your pubspec.yaml:**

```
dependencies: 
  link_text: ^0.2.0
```

**Then:**

```
final String _hyperlink = 'StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: LinkText(
        _hyperlink,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I think this is text widget not Text Field widget

Comment: Ahh I see, my bad. Perhaps you could retrieve the input value of the TextField like this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input, and then pass that value to a  Flutter url_launcher https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Answer (score -1):

This uses the hacky solution of putting a RichText widget over the top of an invisible TextField:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:link_text/link_text.dart';
import 'package:transparent_pointer/transparent_pointer.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

TextEditingController textCont = TextEditingController();

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    textCont.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Stack(
          children: [
            TextField(
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: null,
                controller: textCont,
                autofocus: true,
                style: TextStyle(
                  letterSpacing: 0,
                  fontSize: 24,
                  height: null,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                )),
            TransparentPointer(
              child: LinkText(
                textCont.text,
                textStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 24, height: null, letterSpacing: 0),
                linkStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    letterSpacing: 0,
                    height: null),
                onLinkTap: (link) async {
                  final Uri _url = Uri.parse(link);
                  await launchUrl(_url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It uses the already existing https://pub.dev/packages/link_text package to parse the text and return a RichText span where the URLs are clickable links. The TransparentPointer (https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_pointer) widget passes through tap gestures through the stack so you can still interact with the TextField below the LinkText widget.

LinkText is a bit inflexible, so to change the style of URLs you'll have to fork it and edit the source code. The RegEx it uses to detect URLs is a bit limited too, it requires all URLs to start with http:// or https://. Linkify is a possibly better solution, but I found that the way it handles humanising links and styles URLs made it impossible to easily align it with the invisible TextField underneath.

edit:

If you are going to attempt this, it's also worth noting that for the above solution to work, you're going to have to modify the link_text package to add a whitespace character to all line breaks, due to a bug(?) in how RichText renders empty lines compared to Text: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/121715